# How can I get an answer specific URL for a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support

I have seen that there are plenty of answers linking to another answers on Stack Overflow, I just can't seem to find how can I get the proper URL that will highlight that answer.

Comment: Use the share button below the answer to obtain a link.

Comment: You can click the "share" link under the answer.

Comment: was wondering myself too about that, somehow I didn't notice all those "share" links. Maybe since I was expecting to get the URL from the timestamp like in Twitter etc. (of course the timestamp in that case [if it becomes a url you can right-click to copy] shouldn't be time-related, if it changes time when user edit their answer)